# Do these three idioms mean the same thing?

Tags: idioms

Do these three idioms mean the same thing?

> "to take a stand"
>
> "to take a side"
>
> "to take a position"

The context is this: "Wikipedia should not **take a side** but just share with the readers the different opinions objectively."

Comment: No, they don't.

Answer (score 1):

The question can be answered using Google search, however, here's the basic information:

1. **"Take a stand"**

   - To publicly express an opinion
   - **(against someone or something)** - To take a position in opposition to someone or something; to oppose or resist someone or something.
   - Adopt a firm position about an issue, as in ***She was more than willing to take a stand on abortion rights.***
   - Alludes to the military sense of *stand*, **"hold one's ground against an enemy."**
   - To publicly express an opinion about something, especially to say whether you support or are against something *(usually + on)*
2. **"Take a side"** - also **take somebody's side** and **take the side of somebody**

   - To agree with or support someone; side with somebody.
   - **(take sides)** - To choose one side of an argument.
   - **(take sides)** - To support one person, group, or opinion over another.
   - **(take sides)** - Support or favor one party in a dispute.
   - **(take sides)** - To associate with and support a particular faction, group, cause, or person..
3. **"Take a position"**

   - To buy or sell short; that is to own or to owe some amount on an asset or derivative security.
   - **(take up a position)** - To start in the job.

Comment: Thank you 1+ If I understand well, then the 1st and the 2nd are pretty equal while the 3rd one is the exception. Isn't it?

Comment: I've heard other contexts where **"take a position"** meant something different, however, I don't have any proof and can't find those now but well, yes, it does mean something very different from the first two. Generally, the 1-st and 2-nd idioms aren't equal. Only the **"take a stand against"** and  **"take the side of somebody"** are close in meaning.

Comment: As regards "take a position", you have chosen very specific meanings. There is a sense where it is quite close to the other two e.g. "The politician took a position which neither supported the Government or the Opposition".